# Google Sheet throws Error Array_Literal or not display all

Tags: google-sheets

I have this strange thing going on with google sheet. It throws SOMTIMES error: In ARRAY_LITERAL, an array literal was missing values for one or more rows. And somtimes it gives no error, it just not displays all the values, ie It should result in 15k rows but shows only 6k. This google sheet imports data from 3 other google sheets that have multiple tabs. Overal it imports 21 ranges. What is important this 6k ends on the very first google sheets imported, it don't imports next two. But I am not sure if it's always like this.

As said somtimes it shows error, somtimes do not show all values. I've noticed that if I wait until sheet is loaded, so waiting for couple of seconds it's ok. But when I try stright away go to bottom it may throw error or not load the data. This sheet is connected to Tableau server. Somtimes refresh fails, probably because of the error, and somtimes it just nit bring all the data. The second thing is much worse cause I'd rather have an error than not get all the data. Can anyone advise on this?

Answer (score 1):

When there is an error in one of the importrange, you need to prevent that error with IFERROR function and in that case you need to build an 21 columns empty values array as (example with 6 columns) :

```
iferror(___________,{"","","","","",""})
```

Comment: To Mike's point, an easier and more succinct way of creating this null array is as follows: `IFERROR(___________, SPLIT(REPT("~",20),"~",1,0))` (where the number `20` here is always 1 less than the number of null columns you need). The tilde symbol could be anything; I just tend to use it because it stands out as a delimiter as opposed to, say, the letter `a` which could cause confusion when glancing at a formula.

Comment: thx Erik, it is a better solution !

Comment: Thanks for responses but this still will not bring all values to tableau, and this is major issue, i'd rather get an errorr while extract is refreshing than extract refreshed with some of the data, is this Gogle Sheet issue is normal?  Or this is something that should not happen?